# Nginx php files loading slow

Tags: php, apache, batch-file, nginx, php-7

EDIT: I have noticed the first time you visit it to goes fast, and it also goes fast if you close the browser tab and re-visit it, but if you simply reload or visit it when you have a tab of it open it goes slow, it is really confusing.

today I come with a problem about PHP CGI, I am brand new to nginx and have just installed it, when I noticed I need to start PHP cgi also with it because with IIS it started it for me. so I start php with batch file below but the problem is... slow php files, they load really slowly even if its just html in them.

```
@ECHO off
echo Starting PHP, please wait!
C:\nginx\php7\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9054 -c C:\nginx\php7\php.ini
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1>NUL
ping 127.0.0.1 >NUL
EXIT
```

Am I doing anything wrong with my batch file or nginx config below? (I have 2 configs) the example.com one is the website with a .php file and the nginx (localhost) just has index.html

localhost loads super fast but example.com one loads really slow because of php.

nginx.conf
    worker_processes  1;

```
#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox\websites\local_website;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            if (!-e $document_root$document_uri){return 404;}
            fastcgi_pass localhost:9054;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    include vhosts/*.conf;
}
```

example.com.conf

```
server {
    listen   ***.***.**.***:80;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;

    root C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox\websites\php_website;
    index index.php index.html;

    log_not_found off;
    charset utf-8;

    #access_log  logs/example.com-access.log  main;

    location ~ /\. {allow all;}

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(|/)$ /index.php?url=$1;
        rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(|/)$ /index.php?url=$1;
        rewrite ^/(.*)\.htm$ /$1.php;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-e $document_root$document_uri){return 404;}
        fastcgi_pass localhost:9054;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exactly same problem as you do. try changing your fastcgi_pass.

from this

> fastcgi_pass localhost:9054

to this

> fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9054